# Weebly Migration to Wordpress

Tags: pages

I have some Weebly pages that I'd like to migrate to a new domain I set up for Wordpress. I've tried a couple of methods such as exporting an XML file or using CMS2CMS, but they all seem like they require FTP access, which Weebly unceremoniously prevents their users from accessing.

Does anyone have any tips on Weebly migration to Wordpress? It would save me a lot of work formatting my pages from scratch.

Many thanks.

Comment: sound like you should ask weebly's support

Answer (score 1):

Weekly, like wix and other drag-drop website development app, REALLY prevents migration to WordPress. I usually come across with clients with similar requests but we end manually setting up a WordPress and just use the weebly/wix design as basis.

So to answer your question, no sorry, there's no way.

Comment: if a page is published on the internet, there is no way to "prevent migration" i is just harder. Most likely you can automate exporting all kind of stuff, it is just not very helpful as it is not going to be in any useful structure, but if you must you will be able to use it to make a wordpress site out of it